# Login and Out in Wordpress Menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I've written this login/logout for my functions.php in my wordpress theme.  The problem is, it's showing a login/logout link in all menus both primary and secondary.  Is there a way to get it to appear only in secondary?

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {

    ob_start();
    wp_loginout('index.php');
    $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $items .= '<li>'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';

return $items;
}
```

Comment: This is probably better asked on [wordpress.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use the `$theme_location` to check if it is the primary or secondary location before adding the link.

```
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'secondary' ) {
        ob_start();
        wp_loginout('index.php');
        $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $items .= '<li>'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```